# Non-existence of a continous-norm on a sequence space.

Tags: functional-analysis

For $U\cong \prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}}  \mathbb{R}$ equipped with the product topology, i have already shown, that $U$ is a Frechet-Space w.r.t. the frechet-metric. How to prove that there exists no continous norm on $U$?

Comment: A norm on $U$ is continuous if and only if its unit ball is a neighbourhood of $0$ in $U$. How do the neighbourhoods of $0$ in $U$ look?

Comment: One could a neighborhood of 0 for a given $\epsilon>0$ as the Cartesian Product of unitballs $B_{i,\epsilon}(0)$, where i is the $i$'th coordinate Projection.

Comment: "equipped with the product topology"; the product topology is not that. What you describe would produce the box topology.

Comment: oh then i misunderstood that. Could you help me out. Cause general definitions are not that clear for me. so far i got, that due to the product topology: the canonical projections are continuous.

Comment: Do you know how the product topology is defined?

Comment: what i got from wiki is that the prod. topology on $X:=\prod X_{i}$ is defined by the sets $p_{i}^{-1}(U)$, where $p_{i}$ are the continuous canonical projections $X\rightarrow X_{i}$ and U are open substes of $X_{i}$. But this $X$ is defined as cartesian product according to Wiki.

Comment: Here, we have $X_i =\mathbb{R}$ for all $i$. That description is not so good for the first encounters with the product topology, IMO. Let's describe it thus: An elementary open set in $\prod X_i$ is a set of the form $\prod V_i$, where each $V_i\subset X_i$ is open, _and all but finitely many_ of the $V_i$ are the space $X_i$ itself. An open set is a union of elementary open sets. So a neighbourhood basis at $0$ for $U = \prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{R}$ is formed by sets of the form $\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}I_n$, where each $I_n$ is an open interval containing $0$, and for all but

Comment: finitely many $n$, we have $I_n = \mathbb{R}$. Now think how that would not be compatible with being contained in the unit ball of a norm.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand a bit on the comments. Focus on two tasks:

1. In your space, every open set containing $0$ contains a line through $0$. [Daniel Fischer's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850588/non-existence-of-a-continous-norm-on-a-sequence-space#comment1754065_850588) should help with this part.
2. If $\|\cdot\|$ is a continuous norm, then $\{x:\|x\|<1\}$ is an open set that does not contain any line through $0$.

Comment: Ok the first task is now obvious with @Daniel Fischer's comment.   For the 2. task: The open unitball is some sort of sets, each with finite intersections of open slices and thus it contains a line through 0.   A line through zero has the form $\{rv: r\in \mathbb{R}\}$. With the homogenity of the norm one will get, that not all points on the line have norm $<1$. But where is the continuity included here?